# GraphQLError: Expected type \"StatusInput\" to be an object

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, mutation

I can create a project in Apollo Sandbox - below is the copy of Project copy from Apollo Sandbox

```json
{"data": {"createProject": {"_id": "65952c08576a8d317dc4df47", "description": "front end", "name": "new react", status": [{"code": "a", "launch": "c", "content": "b", "planning": "d","qa": "f", "start": "g", "ux": "h" }]}}
```

however I added mutation on client side as per below

```
mutation createProject($name: String! $description: String! $status: [StatusInput]!) {    createProject(name: $name, description: $description, status: $status) { _id name description status {start planning ux content code qa launch }}}
```

can below is the useQuery code for the submit handler

```js
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  try {
    const mutationRes = await createProject({
      variables: {
        name: formState.name,
        description: formState.description,
        status: formState.status,
      },
    });

    console.log(mutationRes);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

I am able to see the response in network tab of name, description and status but I get 400 status code stating that `GraphQLError: Expected type "StatusInput" to be an object."`

Server Side typeDef:
Input

```
input StatusInput { start: String! planning: String! ux: String! content: String! code: String! qa: String! launch: String! project: ID! }
```

and Mutation

```
createProject( name: String! description: String! status: [StatusInput]! ): Project
```

Comment: I recently started posting question to get some help and thank you for editing the question :)

Comment: What's the value of `formState.status`?

Comment: formState.status values are enum values for example   <option value="start">Started</option> <option value="planning">Project Planning</option> which will be drop down option.

Comment: But your mutation and schema say that the `status` variable must be an array of `StatusInput` objects, with `start`, `planning`, `ux`, `content`, `code`, `qa`, `launch`, `project` properties

Comment: I changed the model and schema - as per answer in updated schema status takes array of enum which allows to select one value at a times which will be the current status and in type def for Project we can pass the enum Status to the status.

Comment: Yeah, that might also work, we cannot tell which solution is the appropriate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed schema

```
    status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["start", "planning", "ux", "content", "code", "qa", "launch"],
  },
```

type def

```
enum Status {
start
planning
ux
content
cde
qa
launch
```

}

```
  type Project {
_id: ID!
name: String!
description: String!
status: Status!
}
```

with enum I was able to assign project status and solved the problem - for any more info please feel free to contact me